# error creating class Getter and Setter with Pojo

Tags: rest-assured

I'm learning to work with setter and getter, but I got a Json that was too complex for me.

can you help me?

It's a request that I need to send, the Json is the one below.

```json
{
    "properties": {
        "headers": {
            "eventLayout": "qa",
            "eventReferenceDate": "2021-09-22"
        }
    },
    "routing_key": "tvm.teste.teste.UPDATED",
    "payload": "string",
    "payload_encoding": "string"
}
```

it has two objects, but whenever I go to create and run the test, I receive bad-Request because I didn't provide the complete json, following the structure below.

**`{`
`"properties": {`
`"headers": {etc...}`**

Here's how I implemented my code.

```java
package com.automation.models;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class PostRequestPojo {
    public static class Properties {
        private Headers headers;

        public Properties() {}

        public Properties(Headers headers) {
            this.headers = headers;
        }

        public Headers getHeaders() {
            return headers;
        }

        public void setHeaders(Headers headers) {
            this.headers = headers;
        }
    }

    @JsonProperty("eventLayout") public String eventLayout;

    public String getEventLayout() {
        return eventLayout;
    }

    public void setEventLayout(String eventLayout) {
        this.eventLayout = eventLayout;
    }

    @JsonProperty("eventReferenceDate") public String eventReferenceDate;

    public String getEventReferenceDate() {
        return eventReferenceDate;
    }

    public void setEventReferenceDate(String eventReferenceDate) {
        this.eventReferenceDate = eventReferenceDate;
    }

    @JsonProperty("routing_key") public String routing_key;

    public String getRouting_key() {
        return routing_key;
    }

    public void setRouting_key(String routing_key) {
        this.routing_key = routing_key;
    }

    @JsonProperty("payload") public String payload;

    public String getPayload() {
        return payload;
    }

    public void setPayload(String payload) {
        this.payload = payload;
    }

    @JsonProperty("payload_encoding") public String payload_encoding;

    public String payload_encoding() {
        return payload_encoding;
    }

    public void payload_encoding(String payload_encoding) {
        this.payload_encoding = payload_encoding;
    }

    public PostRequestPojo() {
        "properties" : {
            "headers" : {eventLayout = "qa", eventReferenceDate = "2021-09-22";
    }
};
routing_key = "UPDATED";
payload = "string";
payload_encoding = "string";
}
}
```

I instantiate the Properties and Headers method within the method I created to run the tests, but I always receive 400 - BAD Request